# Symbol not found - CUnit on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macports, avr-gcc, cunit

I just installed CUnit on Snow Leopard with MacPorts/DarwinPorts. The installation went fine, however, I get en error when trying to run the unit tests:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _acs_map
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libcunit.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/lib/libcunit.1.dylib
Trace/BPT trap
```

Has anyone come across this problem or has anyone successfully got CUnit working on Snow Leopard some other way?

Answer (score 6):

resolved by linking ncurses (-lncurses) in build.